# adding gaussian noise to all tensorflow variables

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, noise

I'm working on a project which needs to evaluate the performance of CNN/RNN after adding noise to all the variables. For example, if we have an simple MLP, I want to add a random gaussian noise to all the weight parameters, which is not difficult. However, it doesn't seem easy to manipulate the variables for RNN. For example, the variables inside the `tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell` are encapsulated and not accessble for users.

I found a possible way to do this by using the `tf.train.saver()` function. I can print all the variables including the encapsulated variables. However, how to modify the value of all the variables is still not clear.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `tf.trainable_variables` ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables)) or `tf.global_variables` ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables)) to get those variables, and add noisy to them.